# User-control with no default value in form designer?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, properties, user-controls

I have created a custom user-control and I want to use it in other projects.
But when I add my user-control on a form in other project the properties which I have put in my user-control gets default value in form designer file...

I want this only happens if I change the default value of the property not as soon as I added it on the form in other project.
I tried `[DesignOnly(true)]` but this time not only there was no default value on the form designer file, it didn't get added after I changed it's value in the property window.

**Edit:**

I have this on my user-control...

```
        [DisplayName("(MiladiDate)")]
        public DateTime MiladiDate
        {
            get { return settedDate; }
            set
            {
                settedDate = new DateTime(value.Year, value.Month, value.Day);
                System.Globalization.PersianCalendar pc = new System.Globalization.PersianCalendar();
                gy = pc.GetYear(settedDate);
                gm = pc.GetMonth(settedDate);
                gd = pc.GetDayOfMonth(settedDate);
                this.SetDate(settedDate);
            }
        }
```

as soon as I add this UC to windows form in other project the following line is added in form designer file:

```
this.persianDateTimePicker1.MiladiDate = new System.DateTime(2019, 1, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0);
```

But I don't want this to happen as soon as I added the UC and only happens when I change the default value of MiladiDate property in property windows (When clicked on UC).

Comment: What values should the UserControl properties have?  Post example code.  Your title makes no sense.  Is this WinForms?  WPF?  etc.

Comment: @LarsTech I know sorry just pasted the wrong title... fixed it and new info added

Comment: What should the value of MiladiDate be when the user puts your control on the form?

Comment: @LarsTech In DateTimePicker when you add it on form the value in not set in designer and it shows current date each time the programs runs... But if the user changes the default value in property window then the picked value added in designer and it shows the picked datetime each time the program runs and it doesn't gets the current datetime of windows... I want the same trait for my UC

Comment: Try `[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]` above the property.

Comment: @LarsTech I tried that. But when I use that not only the default value is not added in designer when the UC is created... I doesn't get added after I change the value in property windows.

Comment: I'm still not sure what you want.  See the [DateTimePicker source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/DateTimePicker.cs).  The Value property is towards the middle of the page.  Maybe that will help you.